# change the year range when plotting with seaborn

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
myDataTradeSWE = myDataTrade[(myDataTrade['from']=='SWE') & (myDataTrade['Year'] > 2013)]

myDataTradeSWE.head(10)
```

How can I change the year range so it only shows 2014 AND 2018 ?

Comment: When asking such questions, better to post the data for an example. Also, see my answer - was that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean **or**, not **and**, since a row can't be 2014 AND 2018 at the same time :)

```py
myDataTradeSWE = myDataTrade[(myDataTrade['from']=='SWE') & ((myDataTrade['Year'] == 2014) | (myDataTrade['Year'] == 2018))]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the comparison operators. You need to replace your `>` with `==`, and then you need to add `| (myDataTrade ['Year'] == 2018)`.

If I understand correctly you search, your code should look like this. This will change the range of the year when plotting:

```
myDataTradeSWE = myDataTrade[(myDataTrade['from']=='SWE') &
    ((myDataTrade['Year'] == 2014) | (myDataTrade['Year'] == 2018))]

myDataTradeSWE.head(10)
```